# CMP Function - "ручное изменение"

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

> я писал этот вопрос в комментариях в своем предыдущем вопросе, но так
>   как это отдельный вопрос - я задаю его отдельно

допустим у нас массив вида:
 `array(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)`, нужно чтобы 3 была на первом месте - `array(3, 1, 2, 5, 6)` как это реализовать именно через `cmp-функцию`?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, речь идёт о пользовательской функции, вызываемой из функции usort(). Уточняю этот момент, потому что пользовательские функции могут иметь разное название и вызываться из других функций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, функция сортировки должна выглядеть так:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b)
        return 0;

    if ($a == 3)
        return -1;
    if ($b == 3)
        return 1;

    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 5, 6);

usort($a, "cmp");

echo "<pre>\n";
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
echo "</pre>\n";
```

P.S. За основу взят пример из http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php

**UPD** Порядок проверки вот такой странный:

```
$a = 3, $b = 2,
$a = 6, $b = 3,
$a = 5, $b = 3,
$a = 1, $b = 3,
$a = 2, $b = 3,
$a = 1, $b = 2,
$a = 6, $b = 1,
$a = 5, $b = 1,
$a = 2, $b = 1,
$a = 5, $b = 2,
$a = 6, $b = 5,
```

Comment: не подскажите еще как именно работает эта функция? почему оправляется `$a` и `$b` и что будет в них храниться? `($a, $b)` - `(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 6) |  (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3) (2, 5), (2, 6) и т.д.` я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @cmd, в ответе написал.

Answer (score 1):

Из описания usort():
"Функция сравнения должна возвращать целое, которое меньше, равно или больше нуля, если первый аргумент является соответственно меньшим, равным или большим чем второй."

Нормальным порядком следует считать порядок по возрастанию. Если мы хотим, чтобы функция usort считала тройку самым маленьким числом - мы должны показывать -1, когда она стоит первым аргументом, и +1, когда вторым.

А в остальном - без аномалий.

```
$common = array(1,2,3,5,6);
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) return 0;
    if ($a == 3) return -1;
    if ($b == 3) return 1;
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($common, 'cmp');
var_dump($common);
```

```
array (size=5)
  0 => int 3
  1 => int 1
  2 => int 2
  3 => int 5
  4 => int 6
```

P.S. К тому же результату приводит использование usort() с анонимной функцией сравнения:

```
$common = array(1,2,3,5,6);
$num = 3;
usort($common, function($a,$b) use($num){
    if ($a == $b) return 0;
    if ($a == $num) return -1;
    if ($b == $num) return 1;
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
);
var_dump($common);
```

В приведённой реализации число 3 - это параметр контекста, заданный посредством опции use(). Такой подход позволяет без особых хлопот протестировать сортировку при разных значениях параметра $num.